# Extract last 1-3 numbers if they are numbers and put them into their own column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a temp table (#testTempTbl1) that i created in SQL in SSMS. i am trying to get a new column to have only the last 1 to 3 characters at the end of the string if they are numbers extracted from an existing column in the table and put them into their own column.

not sure if doing a if statement would be best or another method

The column i want to pull from is Description and it has values like ones below:

```
part3_sec4_line1_F3_DIR_DESC_1


part3_sec4_line1_F3_DIR_PAS_13

part3_sec4_line1_F3_DIR_FORGEN_12
```

The new column i am trying to just get the numbers at the end, some are 1 to 3 numbers at the end after the last '_':

```
1

12

13

12
```

Thank you in advance.

I am using SSMS.

Comment: Are the numerals always preceded by a `_`? Are there always the same amount of `_` in the strings? What version is your ***Server*** (not the SSMS client application)?

Comment: @MatBailie yes the numbers are always after a _ and yes there is always the same number of _ in the string. The version i am not sure how to check that, its the most recent version of ssms

Comment: @MatBailie, Check this out
`SELECT  
    Description,
    REVERSE(Description) AS ReversedDescription,
    PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(Description)) AS PatIndexResult,
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Description), 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(Description)) - 1)) AS ExtractedNumbers
FROM #testTempTbl1;
`

Comment: @SenthilPNathan , thank you for that, is there a way to add that ExtractedNumbers column to the temp table? #testTempTbl1

Comment: `select @@version` (SSMS has nothing to do with this, SSMS is just the app that talks to to the server, but the server does the work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    CREATE TABLE #testTempTbl1 (
        ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Description NVARCHAR(100)
    );
    
    -- Insert
    INSERT INTO #testTempTbl1 (ID, Description)
    VALUES
        (1, 'part3_sec4_line1_F3_DIR_DESC_1'),(2, 'part3_sec4_line1_F3_DIR_PAS_13'),
        (3, 'part3_sec4_line1_F3_DIR_FORGEN_12'), (4, 'part3_sec4_line1_F3_DIR_PAS_1301');
    
    -- Add a new column 
    ALTER TABLE #testTempTbl1 ADD ExtractedNumbers NVARCHAR(5);
    
    -- Update the new column
    UPDATE #testTempTbl1 SET ExtractedNumbers = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Description), 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(Description)) - 1));
    
    --select
SELECT * FROM #testTempTbl1;
```

Comment: Slightly shorter example, using RIGHT instead of SUBSTRING (but still relying on REVERSE) : https://dbfiddle.uk/teZNQqdx